# how to find specific object inside array in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have object like this:

```
{    
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "654625943108039f4960125b"
    },
    "text": "c1",
    "replies": [{
        "parentCommentId": {
            "$oid": "654625943108039f4960125b"
        },
        "replyId": "f2ff36d9-ce4f-468c-98dd-0e6a0acf85c0",
        "text": "c1-r1-r1-r3",
        "immediateParent": "b0b1dda0-493a-473b-bc11-7efc9935e4fe",
        "ancestors": [{
            "parentReplyId": "b0b1dda0-493a-473b-bc11-7efc9935e4fe",
            "commentId": "654625943108039f4960125b"
        }]
    }, {
        "parentCommentId": {
            "$oid": "654625943108039f4960125b"
        },
        "replyId": "5ecd2ce9-5347-4722-86d4-e35e52fbb3ef",   
        "text": "sample1",
        "immediateParent": "312e2000-2793-4be7-8a20-f782d32401cc",
        "ancestors": [{
            "parentReplyId": "312e2000-2793-4be7-8a20-f782d32401cc",
            "commentId": "654625943108039f4960125b"
        }]
 }
```

I want to find `replyId: 5ecd2ce9-5347-4722-86d4-e35e52fbb3ef` from the above object in mongo.

I tried this but it returns all the objects:

```
const replies = await genericDb.collection('comments').findOne(
    { _id: new ObjectId(commentId), 'replies.replyId': replyId },
    { 'ancestors.$': 1 }
);
```

Update:

Tried with aggregation pipeline but still no luck

```
const ancestors = await genericDb.collection('comments').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: new ObjectId(commentId), "replies.replyId": replyId } },
    { $unwind: "$replies.ancestors" },
]).toArray();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jlKT1EMMuiA continue projecting whatever after

Comment: @cmgchess What does double $$ mean in   `$$reply` in the above play ground?

Comment: It's the one mentioned in `as: reply`. If you don't use `as` you will need to use `$$this`. So like an alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to single out the object from the `replies` array that matched your `replyId` condition you need to use `$elemMatch` which will then allow you to use the `$` positional operator. Aggregate is much more capable but here is an example with `find()`:

```js
const replies = await genericDb.collection('comments').find({
  "_id": ObjectId(commentId),
  "replies": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "replyId": replyId
    }
  }
},
{
  "replies.$": 1,
  // "replies.ancestors.$": 1, //< or with just ancestors
  "_id": 0
})
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dFqinh3BIkS) for working example.